# Class.method is not a function using ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I create a class and I want to use the method in routes in my node.js application.
A simple snippet code describe a smilar issue that I faced in my real app.

myClass.js:

```
class MyClass {
    static async sayHi(name) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            return `Hello ${name}`
        }, 3000)
    }
}

module.exports = new MyClass()
```

index.js:

```
const MyClass = require('./myClass');
console.log(MyClass.sayHi)
```

I got this error:

```
undefined
```

Trying:

```
console.log(MyClass.sayHi('Hello'))
```

returns:

```
MyClass.sayHi is not a function
```

Comment: Where do you test `console.log(MyClass.sayHi('Hello'))`? you never export the class therefore you would never be able to call this code externally (FWIW this is exactly how you should be calling the function as it's static).

Comment: Don't export `module.exports = new MyClass()`, export the `MyClass` itself!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're exporting an instance of the class - when importing, you have an instance, not the actual class. Calling the imported object `MyClass` is confusing - maybe call it `myClassInstance` instead, which would make it clear what the problem is.

If you have an instance, and want to call a static method on the class, reference the `.constructor` property.

If you want to return something asynchronously, best to use a Promise, and then call `.then` on the `sayHi` call to consume the Promise:

```js
class MyClass {
  static sayHi(name) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(`Hello ${name}`);
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
}

const myClassInstance = new MyClass();
// module.exports = myClassInstance;

// index.js:

// const myClassInstance = require('./index');
myClassInstance.constructor.sayHi('foo')
  .then(console.log);
```

No need for the static method to be `async`, since you're already returning a Promise explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

You are exporting an instance of `MyClass`. Static methods are not called on instances of the class, but rather on the class itself.

If you export `MyClass` like so: `module.exports = MyClass`, your second approach should work.

edit:

As @T.J. Crowder pointed out. If the class is in a file called MyClass.js, import from there instead of index.

Comment: The import is also incrrect. Should be `require("./MyClass")`, not `require("./index")`.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It won't work, but I guess that will be a question in itself. T.J. Crowder, I have edited original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change line from instance to Class itself, as **Static** methods are the methods that can be called without creating an **instance** of class.

```
module.exports = MyClass;
```

and change the require to the file name

```
 const MyClass = require('./myClass.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

@Murtaza Hussain is right.

As the method is static. you can just export the class instead creating an instance.

```
module.exports = MyClass;
```